# How to make shortcode enabled in JSON Feeds?

Tags: shortcode, feed

I was creating an Android App for my WordPress website and it shows posts through JSON feeds. So I use the WordPress plugin JSON API as well. Everything work except the shortcodes. I have viral quiz for WordPress plugin on the website and it uses shortcode. But it shows just that shortcode as text while using the feeds. 
So how can the shortcodes work with the plugin so the quiz and other shortcodes work on my mobile App?

Comment: Please specify the names of plugins you use by utilizing [capital letters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_case#Capitalisation) for their names. It's impossible to separate names from the question terms.

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/

Comment: What does it mean *"viral quiz"*? Please, **edit your question**, not comment on it.

Comment: Viral Quiz is a premium plugin that help making quizzes. After that using the shortcode we can display that quiz on the post.